# Clearing a ComboBox and resetting index to -1

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been working on a database project for my database classes but I am stuck at the most ridiculous thing; clearing a ComboBox of values in one of my forms. I've been trying to figure out how to do this for hours, but I cannot do it. The ComboBox has a control source linking it to an attribute which is a data type of Date/Time, formatted as short time (hh:ss)

I've tried a few things, but nothing really works, like:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
```

but that won't work because the Items property doesn't even exist in Access's version of VB, I run Access 2019 which has VB for Apps 7.1. Most things on the Internet suggest this approach.

I've also tried a rather quirky method:

```
index = Combo39.ListIndex
Dim indexc As Integer
indexc = 0
If index = -1 Then
    'do nothing because its already empty
Else
    Do
        Combo39.RemoveItem (indexc)
        If indexc = index Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        indexc = indexc + 1
    Loop
End If
```

This code basically loops until the number of times the loop has cycled is the same as the index number of the combo box. I am not sure why, but it doesn't work. It does appear to remove some things, but not everything. It's as if the loop breaks early.

I am in huge need of help, I've run completely dry on how to do this one simple thing. I would greatly appreciate help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your combobox seems to have a list of values as its rowsourcet, all you need is to clear this:

```
Me!Combo39.RowSource = ""
```